# Select Result Different On Float Data Type MariaDB 10.4.8

Tags: mariadb, select, sum

On MariaDB

I have simple table with float data type

```
CREATE TABLE `testatt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nilai` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

when I insert data like this

```
insert into testatt (nilai) values (6.83333)
```

and then I select

```
select * from testatt
```

the results become

```
6.8333301544
```

this is normal or need more configuration.

I using MariaDB 10.4.8

Comment: This is normal when using floating point values. If you need the value to always be consistent, use a `DECIMAL` data type with the precision set as you need it 

Comment: but IF using `DECIMAL` can't get comma value

Comment: previously this issue i solved using `CAST(value as float)` but mariadb under version 10.4.5 can't `cast as float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FLOAT`, by definition, holds about 7 significant digits.  Any digits after that will be 'junk'.  Similarly, `DOUBLE` has a limit of about 16 significant digits.

```
6.83333000000000000000000 -- what you tried to insert
6.8333301544  -- what you got when displaying
1 234567xxxx  -- counting the significant digits
```

The reason for all this is that `FLOAT` is defined as a 24-bit *binary* number plus exponent and sign.  24 bits can hold only 16M different values.  6.8333301544... is the closed possible 24-bit value to 6.83333.

As pointed out, you could store it in

```
DECIMAL(m,n) with n>=5 and m>=n+1
```

This can store exactly 6.83333 without any loss.  (It does not store in "binary".)

You imply that 10.4.8 is different than 10.4.5; please provide more details.  The definition of `FLOAT` was standardized in the early 1980s (cf IEEE-754).  MySQL and MariaDB have simply used the standard.

`6.83333` may have come from `41/6`.  such a quotient *cannot* be represented exactly in either `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL`.

Lesson:  Use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for approximate measurements (temperature, area, etc)  Use `DECIMAL` for money.